# <Psych::SyntaxError: did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, yaml

When I start the server, I get this error:

```
I18n::InvalidLocaleData
can not load translations from /Users/Apple/myapp-website-freelance/config/locales/fr.yml: #<Psych::SyntaxError: (/Users/Apple/myapp-website-freelance/config/locales/fr.yml): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 2 column 3>
```

Although, the yaml file seems normal at line 2 column 3:

```
fr:
  Electronics_Circuits_Simulator_Realistic_Interface: "Simulateur de circuits electroniques. Interface reelle."
```

Any idea?

Comment: In my case it was `a: *default\n  b: 1` in place of `a:\n  <<: *default\n  b: 1`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This error is often misleading and points the wrong line out

Look for extra spaces in the entire YML file and try to replace all enclosing single quotes by "", it should work !

One possible reason is:

```
default: &default
  a: 1
production: *default
  b: 2
```

in place of:

```
default: &default
  a: 1
production:
  <<: *default
  b: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

and if you are working with many projects make sure your on the sites section the  hyphens **-** are in line look at the pic below where i have the green line.

Comment: Thanks just used image because i need to draw that line

Answer (score 1):

Check for any extra whitespace in your YML file. Also, if you were like me you might forgot to remove `{}` in YML template.

```
# Read about fixtures at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html

# This model initially had no columns defined. If you add columns to the
# model remove the '{}' from the fixture names and add the columns immediately
# below each fixture, per the syntax in the comments below
#
one: {}
# column: value
#
two: {}
# column: value
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a comma at the end of a line from a bad copy/paste elsewhere. Removing the comma restored the YAML file back to normal use (my `application.yml` in this case). The error is apparently covering a wide variety of YAML syntax issues. I suspect it means that the YAML parser could not go to the next line in the YAML file because of a breaking syntax error on the current line.

Answer (score 1):

In may case it was missing quotas for `password` fields with symbols like "!@#". Check your yaml file with [yaml validator](http://www.yamllint.com/) .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but in my case, it was not *blank spaces* as shown in @Dijiflex's solution but it was an apostrophe or single quote character like in the example below;

```
pages:
    title: "I don't have time this evening"
```

Please take note of the word **don't** so what I did was to escape it as below

```
pages:
    title: "I don\\'t have time this evening"
```

I hope you have the idea now?
Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

If you are parsing the YAML through ERB first, check your final YAML output (e.g. embedding of environment variables) to see if they contain invalid YAML, e.g. incomplete strings, etc.