# ERB did not find expected comment or line break while scanning a block scalar

Tags: ruby, erb

I've an ERB template in YAML file which is parsed successfully and looks like so

```yaml
---
name: message_from_json_to_raw
config:
  definition: <% 
    output = ''
    if "splunk_index".eql? env_index
      output << ' | spath output=_raw path=msg | eval _raw = split(_raw,"\n") | extract'
    end %>
    <%= output %>
```

I want the output variable to contain `| extract` at the end irrespective of the `if` block execution. So I tried the following approaches

```yaml
config:
  definition: <% 
    output = ''
    if "splunk_index".eql? env_index
      output << ' | spath output=_raw path=msg | eval _raw = split(_raw,"\n")'
    end %>
    <%= output.concat(" | extract ") %>
```

```yaml
config:
  definition: <% 
    output = ''
    if "splunk_index".eql? env_index
      output << ' | spath output=_raw path=msg | eval _raw = split(_raw,"\n") | extract '
    else 
      output << ' | extract '
    end %>
    <%= output %>
```

```yaml
config:
  definition: <% 
    output = ' | extract '
    if "splunk_index".eql? env_index
      output = ' | spath output=_raw path=msg | eval _raw = split(_raw,"\n")'
    end %>
    <%= output %>
```

```yaml
config:
  definition: <% 
    output = ''
    if "splunk_index".eql? env_index
      output << ' | spath output=_raw path=msg | eval _raw = split(_raw,"\n")'
    end %>
    <% output.concat(' | extract ') %>
    <%= output %>
```

```yaml
config:
  definition: <% 
    output = ''
    if "splunk_index".eql? env_index
      output << ' | spath output=_raw path=msg | eval _raw = split(_raw,"\n")'
    end 
    output << ' | extract ' %>
    <%= output %>
```

All the above approaches given a single error which looks as follows

```
/var/lib/spork/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:377:in `parse': (<unknown>): did not find expected comment or line break while scanning a block scalar at line 5 column 6 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /var/lib/spork/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:377:in `parse_stream'
    from /var/lib/spork/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:325:in `parse'
    from /var/lib/spork/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:291:in `safe_load'
```

Any suggestion on what's causing this and a possible fix?
This looks similar to the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44372522/psychsyntaxerror-did-not-find-expected-key-while-parsing-a-block-mapping) but the suggestions don't look related to this situation.

Interestingly, all of the things I tried work perfectly fine when I use the Ruby REPL [here](https://replit.com/languages/ruby). For instance the below one

```rb
require 'erb'

splunk_index = 'splunk_cloud'
template = ERB.new <<-EOF
  <% 
    output = ''
    if "splunk_index".eql? env_index
      output << ' | spath output=_raw path=msg | eval _raw = split(_raw,"\n")'
    end %>
    <% output.concat(' | extract ') %>
    <%= output %>
EOF
puts template.result(binding)
```

Comment: `Psych::SyntaxError` not `ERB`. make sure yaml syntax is correct, then wrap erb around it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the error is telling you the truth: you're missing a line break after your [block scalar](https://yaml-multiline.info/).

`| extract` needs to be followed by a line break before the end of the file or the next key.

The reason that the heredoc example worked is because a heredoc is always terminated by a linebreak [unless you add chomp](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/11/ruby-heredoc/).

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on "` | extract` needs to be followed by a line break before the end of the file or the next key." Should I end the string in the next line, or add a `\n` at the end of string, or something else?